# how to add increments array values with golang

Tags: arrays, go, sum

how to add the following array from top to bottom in golang

example :

input:

[3, 8, 1]

[3, 2, 5]

output:

[6, 0, 7]

input:

[7, 6, 7]

[2, 5, 6]

output:

[9, 1, 4, 1]

here is my code :

```
func main() {
    size := 3
    elements := make([]int, size)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Scanln(&elements[i])
    }
    fmt.Println("2,5,7", elements)
    result := 0
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        result += elements[i]
    }
    fmt.Println("Sum of elements of array:", result)
}
```

Comment: From what I can see, you can just create numbers from the arrays in reverse and sum them. Finally Split them back into single digit arrays. You dont need any looping logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question's input and output samples it seems like you need to take 3 elements for two input arrays and add them together. It's difficulty to understand what you're trying to achieve by following your code snippets... But lemmy assume you're only concerned with those inputs and output samples, then here is what you can do

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  size := 3
  elements1 := make([]int, size)
  elements2 := make([]int, size)
  //take elements for the first input array elements1
  for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
    fmt.Scanln(&elements1[i])
  }

  //take elements for the second input array elements2
  for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
    fmt.Scanln(&elements2[i])
  }

  //output stores our output array
  output := []int{}
  //this store the value to add to the next index eg. 20 + 10 takes 3
  pushToNextIndex := 0

  for i, v := range elements1 {
    sum := v + elements2[i] + pushToNextIndex
    pushToNextIndex = 0

    if sum >= 10 {
        output = append(output, sum%10)
        pushToNextIndex = sum / 10
        continue
    }

    output = append(output, sum)
  }

 //if there is still value after iterating all values then append this as the 
 // new array element
  if pushToNextIndex > 0 {
    output = append(output, pushToNextIndex)
  }

  fmt.Println(output)
 }
```

Please lemmy know if this is not what you're looking for!

Comment: how to input like:
[3, 8, 1]

[3, 2, 5]

output:

[6, 0, 7]

Comment: It should work too! Have you tried it? Here is my go playground with your inputs https://go.dev/play/p/MCqpPTS8BKW